# copy data from one sheet to another?

Tags: vba, excel

Hello i tried this following code to help me copying data from one sheet to another with one condition (copy only the lines with "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" (Range(AB)).I can not see anything when i press on the button.

any help is welcome

```
Sub copier()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")


For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row


    Set src = ws1.Range("A2:AL50") ' la selection des plages de donnees
    Set dest = ws2.Range("A2:AL50")


    If src.Cells(i, 31).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" Then

       '(i,31) for my drop down list


       src.Copy Destination:=dest ' page source
       dest.Value = dest.Value 'destination page

  End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: According to [the MSDN page on Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx), the `Cells(x, y)` property returns a specific cell within your Range. This is relative to the Range whose cell you're locating. In your example, you're referring to `ws1.Range("A2:AL50")`. Does column 32 have the text you're searching for or is it in column 31?

Comment: its a drop down list and it exists in every line and it`s filled with 3 options ,its in column 28 .       If src.Cells(i, 28).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite"

Comment: Column 28 on the worksheet would be referenced to by `src.Cells(i, 28)`. Try this and see if it helps. In your original post you have `src.Cells(i, 31)`.

Comment: Oh, I see why. I thought your problem was that it was not copying any data at all. If you want to copy only the rows that have that value in them, then you should modify your copy/paste code. Currently it is set to copy the entire `Range("A2:AL50")` and paste it for each row that contains that value. You should edit your original post to reflect the previous changes.

Comment: yes exactly that what i want do i need a loop or a sample condition before copy i tried both but doesn`t work

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer because I feel it should be one.

To continue our discussion from the comments, you are trying to copy only the rows that contain the value "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" in Column 28.

I think you could accomplish something like this by doing:

```
Sub copier()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer
    Dim DestinationRow As Integer

    DestinationRow = 1
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        Set src = ws1.Range("A2:AL50")
        Set dest = ws2.Range("A2:AL50")

        If src.Cells(i, 28).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" Then
            src.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=dest.Rows(DestinationRow)
            DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help yes exactly .that's what i need i got an object required error

Comment: The error is here   `Set DestinationRow = 1`    -Object required

Comment: Sorry, change it to `DestinationRow = 1` as well as the `DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1`. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: still the same issue :/

Comment: Did you change both `Set` statements dealing with `DestinationRow`? I realize I made an error here.

Comment: yes actually i changed only the first one the seond statemnt it's already `Set DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1`

Comment: Yes, and that `Set` in front of it is causing your error. Remove it and the code will work. That was my mistake.

Comment: thanks for replying me so quickly , my internet is so slow today , i'll try and go back to you soon. :)

Comment: its gonna be the same thing if i will add another control from the same drop down list ? i tried already it displays Object required       `If src.Cells(i, 31).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" Or src.Cells(i, 31).Value = "Completed – Inventory available / Complété - Inventaire disponible" Then`